# Azure pipelines - build Xamarin.iOS - The iOS SDK version '14.0' is not installed, and no newer version was found

Tags: azure-devops, xamarin.ios

I am trying to build a Xamarin.iOS project in azure pipelines. My Pipeline & agent are using  macOS-10.15. The read me for this agent specification indicates that it contains iOS 14 sdk.

https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md

When running the pipeline I still get an error the the SDK version is not installed.

[image: Build Xamarin.iOS task]

Things i've tried:

- Upgrading the agent specification from macOS-10.14 to macOS-10.15
- Adding SDK, SDK Name & Xcode Version to the "Demands" section of agent job configuration

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer, please check it and feel free to let me know the latest news. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can add task `bash` and enter the script `xcodebuild -showsdks` to check the IOS SDK version, according test result and the [doc](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md#xcode), we can see that the default Xcode version is 11.7 and the IOS SDK version in the hosted agent macOS-10.15 is iOS 13.7.

[image]

[image]

For systems with multiple Xcode versions installed, the current version can be selected by running sudo xcode-select at the command-line.

We can add task Bash and enter the script `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_12_beta.app` to switch the xcode and IOS SDK version.

[image]

**Update1**

You can refer to this doc for more details: [How can I manually select versions of tools on the Hosted macOS agent?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#how-can-i-manually-select-versions-of-tools-on-the-hosted-macos-agent)